# Generalizations of Positive Definiteness

Tags: real-analysis, convex-optimization, tensors, matrix-calculus

What, if any, notions of positive definiteness can be extended to 3rd order tensors (and beyond)?

The reason I ask is because the Hessian matrix of a convex function is positive semi-definite, but trying to evaluate the convexity of matrix valued functions can occasionally result in Hessians that are 3rd order (or greater) tensors. Is there an analog of positive definiteness for such objects? And even if there is, would such a property holding imply that the original function was convex?

Comment: It depends on the order in vector space, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Which vector space are you referring to?

Comment: You want to characterize the "convexity" of a matrix-valued function using its hessian.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if that statement has any meaning. Does "convexity" mean anything in the context of matrix valued functions? If it does, does it imply similar things to convexity in the context of scalar functions? Relatedly, if there is such a thing as a "convex" matrix valued function does it also have a "positive definite" Hessian (which would imply some sort of analog of positive definiteness for higher order tensors)?

Comment: These concept relies on an suitable ordering of the codomain, here space of matrices. That's all